# Using FitText with the change() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fittextjs

How do I trigger the below fittext.js function

```
$.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
            settings = $.extend({
              'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
              'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
            }, options);

        return this.each(function(){

          // Store the object
          var $this = $(this);

          // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
          var resizer = function () {
            $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
          };
    )};
```

using the change() Method?

```
$('#drop').change(function(){
     $('#tf').css('width', $(this).val());
     //resizer(); // does not work
     //$('#tf').fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '40px' });// does not work
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a resize event because the `fittext` plugin listens to the `window`'s resize event to call the internal `resize` method

```
$(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
```

so

```
$('#tf').fitText(1.2, {
    minFontSize: '20px',
    maxFontSize: '40px'
});

$('#drop').change(function () {
    $('#tf').css('width', $(this).val());
    $(window).trigger('resize.fittext');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x4g830kz/) - set the width as 100/300/500

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work fully. Follow these steps: 1-> I entered 500   2-> hit enter   3-> resized the bowser window.  I need the text to resize when the browser window is resized as well.